# Microsoft Graph Powershell Copy / Move message

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I've wrote a little PowerShell function to work with the Microsoft Graph API.

Creation an application with a token for unattended access. This seems to work fine as far as requests for any GET requests (such as retrieve a mailbox email) work fine but struggling to get a POST request to work to move an email from one folder to another ('Inbox' to 'Resolved')

```
# This function moves an email object to a given folder in Outlook in o365
function moveEmail
{
    param(
        $Credential,
        [string] $UserPrincipalName,
        [string] $folderId,
        [string] $folderDestinationId,
        [string] $emailId)

    $Header = Get-Header -theRequest $Credential
    $restUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$UserPrincipalName/mailFolders/$folderId/messages/$emailId/move"
    $Body = @{
        destinationID = $folderDestinationId
    }

    $emailResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $restUrl -Headers $Header -Body $Body -ContentType "application/json"

    return $emailResult
}
```

Response is "Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Looking at the API documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-move?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http I can't see why what I'm producing is malformed

Any guidance would be much apprecaited

Expecting HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-type: application/json

Comment: u missed to convert the body to json, currently its a hashtable.  see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-move?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks Toni,

Tried adding in the line: $json = $Body | ConvertTo-Json

and changing the the email result to: $emailResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $restUrl -Headers $Header -Body $json -ContentType "application/json"

Same result :/

Comment: Aside from the JSON issue, your issue is probably with your headers which you haven't provided info on. What is `Get-Header` and what is the result of `$Header`?

Comment: `function Get-Header
{
    param($theRequest)

    $tokenType = $theRequest.token_type
    $accessToken = $theRequest.access_token

    $theHeader = @{
        Authorization = "$($tokenType) $($accessToken)"
    }

    return $theHeader
}`

Comment: Sorry just assumed the header was fine as I've used the same in the working GET request earlier.

Borrowed from David where you can see the Get-AccessToken function [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68618555/using-powershell-to-process-emails-in-an-o365-mailbox-when-connecting-with-appli)

Comment: $Header consists of the access token passing over to the bearer authorization header.

`@{
 "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0....."
}`

Comment: Then I don't see any other issue with the code as it works for me. Probably your folder/message ID is not correct

Comment: After soring the JSON the code worked fine. Thanks @Toni

Old muggins here was just making myself problems by not passing all the parameters when calling the method. Doh!